# How to update a specific line when receive a new data in React-Native Flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a issue with FlatList, I'm setting up a values on array (This array is created inside the state) and I need to update a specific line on him, when the routine receive a new value.

I tried to loop the state.data, validating the current line key with the key from the new value, but unsuccessful.

Here my code:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        data: [],
        page: 1,
        loading: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData = () => {
        let { data, loading } = this.state;
        data.push({ id: 1,
                    name: "Robert Garcia",
                    wins: 1 // I want to update this and preserve this line
                  });

        loading = false;
        this.setState({ data, loading });
    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <View>
               <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.name}</Text>
               <Text>{item.wins}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            />
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is about deep copy and shallow copy. In your `loadData()` function you created a shallow copy of `this.state`, so your new object is actually the old one and the pure component wouldn't re-render. To fix this just simply change to:

`let { data, loading } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));`

(you can also use another ways of deep copying object)